# delete Grafana Dashboard

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I already added Grafana JSON file in my project and added Grafana Dashboard (UI) in my Grafana account.

Today I decided to eliminate that, so I deleted the JSON file in my project, but when I wanted to delete it within Grafana UI, I had this error: `This dashboard is managed by Grafanas provisioning and cannot be deleted. Remove the dashboard from the config file to delete it.`

How I can delete this dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

It shows you what you need to do.

Go to the config file > remove the dashboard there > delete it. Usually this file is found in: `/usr/local/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`